# convert timestamp to one array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Running in App script, google sheet. I get the timestamp from API and return this result:

```
[[1.6370611672429312E18], [1.63706107263277082E18]],
```

I do this code and work fine, but the problem is not in the array, I need it every time in an array:

```
 const timestamps = [[1.6370611672429312E18], [1.63706107263277082E18]];
for (let i = 0; i < timestamps.length; i++) {
  const timestamp = new Date(timestamps[i][0] / 1000000);
  const convertDate = Utilities.formatDate(timestamp, "GMT", "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
}
```

the result is:

```
1:52:34 PM  Info    11-16-2021 12:52:33
1:52:34 PM  Info    11-16-2021 12:52:33
1:52:34 PM  Info    11-16-2021 12:52:33
```

I need results like that: `1:52:34 PM   Info [[11-16-2021 12:52:33], [11-16-2021 12:50:10]]`

to put in sheet by this code: `sheet.getRange(1,1,convertDate .length, convertDate [0].length).setValues(convertDate );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const timestamps = [[1.6370611672429312E18], [1.63706107263277082E18]];
let convertedDates = []; // Create an array to store the converted dates
for (let i = 0; i < timestamps.length; i++) {
  const timestamp = new Date(timestamps[i][0] / 1000000);
  const convertedDate = Utilities.formatDate(timestamp, "GMT", "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  convertedDates.push([convertedDate]); // Wrap each in [] because this will be printed as a single column
}

const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID).getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
sheet.getRange(1, 1, convertedDates.length, convertedDates[0].length).setValues(convertedDates);
```

Comment: it's work but if I change array time to `[[1637575268], [1637575268], [1637575268]]` , not working give me  time `1/1/1970 0:27:17` why?

Answer (score 0):

```
const timestamps = [[1.6370611672429312E18], [1.63706107263277082E18]];
const toISOStringWithTimezone = date => {
  const pad = n => `${Math.floor(Math.abs(n))}`.padStart(2, '0');
  return date.getFullYear() +
    '-' + pad(date.getMonth() + 1) +
    '-' + pad(date.getDate()) +
    ' ' + pad(date.getHours()) +
    ':' + pad(date.getMinutes()) +
    ':' + pad(date.getSeconds())
};
const hasArrDate = (data = []) => {
  return data.flat().map(v => toISOStringWithTimezone(new Date(v / 1000000)))
}
console.log(hasArrDate(timestamps));
```